# Rails: where not in on has_many through

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, arel

I have the following model

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipe_allergens
  has_many :allergens, through: :recipe_allergens
end
```

I'm trying to find all the recipes that do not have a given set of allergens, so I tried `joins(:allergens).where.not(allergens: { id: allergens })`.

Unfortunately, this does not account for the null case, where a `Recipe` may not have any associated `Allergen`.

I thought the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` that `includes` does would handle this.

How are you supposed to write this query?

**EDIT:**

I got this working with the following, though it seems really gross:

```
joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN recipe_allergens ON recipe_allergens.recipe_id = recipes.id")
      .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN allergens ON allergens.id = recipe_allergens.allergen_id")
      .where(
        Allergen.arel_table[:id].not_in(allergen_ids)
        .or(Allergen.arel_table[:id].eq(nil))
      )
```

Please tell me there's a better way!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
allergenes = Allergene.where #....

allergene_ids = allergenes.pluck(:id)

bad_recipe_ids = RecipeAllergenes.where(allergene_id: allergene_ids)
                                 .pluck(:recipe_id)

recipes = Recipe.where('id NOT IN ?', bad_recipe_ids)
```